# Upper Case Page Header KOMA

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, fancyhdr, capitalization

I am trying change the page header in `scrbook` so that it contains upper case letters. To do so, I am using `fancyhdr` which gives me the required look for all the chapters.

[image]

Unfortunately there is a problem with the page header in the bibliography that still contains lower case letters.

[image]

How can I change this, so that it looks like this?

[image]

I know that if use `book` instead of `scrbook` everythink works fine, but since I am using a lot of other things from scrbook this is really an unwanted option. Usually `scrpage2` is recommended for the use with KOMA-script, but I don't know a way to have upper case letters in the page headers there.

Here is my code

```
    \begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
    @article{Smith2000,
    author = {Smith, John},
    journal = {Journal A},
    number = {1},
    pages = {1--38},
    title = {{Science}},
    volume = {1},
    year = {2000}
    }
    \end{filecontents}

    \documentclass{scrbook}
    \usepackage{biblatex}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \bibliography{mybib}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}

    \makeatletter{%
    \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}%
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
    }\makeatother
    \pagestyle{fancy}


    \begin{document}
    \chapter{Test}
    \blindtext[5]
    \cite{Smith2000}
    \printbibliography
    \blindtext[5]
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to switch from `fancyhdr` to `scrpage2`, add `\MakeUppercase` to the argument of `\fancyhead`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Smith2000,
author = {Smith, John},
journal = {Journal A},
number = {1},
pages = {1--38},
title = {{Science}},
volume = {1},
year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\bibliography{mybib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhead[L]{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\blindtext[5]
\cite{Smith2000}
\printbibliography
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: after researching quite some time I didnt't expect the answer to be that simple, thanks

Comment: adding the `babel` package to this actually produces the error: You haven't defined the language yet.

Comment: @maetra: You need to specify at least one language option, e.g., `\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}`. (The last language is regarded as the document's default language.)

Comment: that is actually what I did, adding the line `\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}` without this babel works fine. But I found a solution that also works with babel.

Answer (score 9):

Here the way to use the package `scrpage2`:

```
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadings
\ohead{\MakeUppercase{\headmark}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
```

The same method is used by `fancyhdr` to get capital letters.

To disable slanted use :`\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}` (Thanks to lockstep)

Comment: You may add `\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}` to disable slanted.

Comment: thanks Marco, I take a closer look at `scrpage` now

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that works fine with the `babel` package is the following code from Markus Kohm

```
   \newcommand*{\MarkBoth}{}
   \let\MarkBoth\markboth
   \renewcommand*{\markboth}[2]{\MarkBoth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#2}}}
```